Скомпилировал программу на C++, библиотека SFML, ошибка при запуске exe файла (G++)
Версия SFML - 2.6.1
Версия G++ - 14.1.0
Код программы:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
   sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 450), "SFML works!");
   sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
   shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

   while (window.isOpen()){
     sf::Event event;
     while (window.pollEvent(event)){
       if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
         window.close();
       }
     }

     window.clear();
     window.draw(shape);
     window.display();
   }

   return 0;
}

Команда для компиляции - g++ .\main.cpp -I include\ -L lib\ -lsfml-main -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window
Все папки и файлы на месте
ошибка открывается после запуска exe файла
ошибка:
The procedure entry point 
_ZNSt15basic_streambuflcSt11char_traitslcEE7seekposESt4fposliESt13
_los_openmode could not be located in the dynamic link librart
C:\Peogramming\C++\SFMLGame\sfml-system-2.dll

Я не умею подключать библиотеки, туториал взял с сайта -> вот этот сайт
Как мне исправить ошибку и что это вообще за ошибка?

¿Бибилиотеку sfml собирали сами?

@user7860670 нет, я скачал сразу готовую

Где-то в PATH лежат конфликтующие DLL (не обязательно от SFML). Решение - подвинуть путь к компилятору в PATH на первое место, чтобы он проверялся первый. (Переменных PATH две, для конкретного пользователя и для всех - у второй приоритет, поэтому ставить в начало ее.)
